# How to mimic word-break: break-word; for IE9, IE11 and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

How to mimic `word-break: break-word;` for IE9, IE11 and Firefox?

It seems to work in Chrome. I have learnt and understood that it is a is non-standard, webkit only.

FYI, I have tried using,

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

And some more like,

```
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Also tried the below mentioned CSS,

```
 word-wrap:  break-word;
 word-break: break-word;
```

But these don't seem to work.

> I can't provide fixed width to the span(which contains the text) by making it `display: block;` explicitly as the text is dynamic and will differ according to the user's Geo-location. Currently we support around 18 languages.

This is how the code looks,

The html,

```
<div id="grid2">
     <span id="theSpan">Product Support</span>
</div>
```

The CSS,

```
#theSpan{
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera 7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
   word-break: break-all;
}

#grid2{
   width: 100px;
}
```

It looks like this,

[image]

I want it to be like,

[image]

**Please note:**
I had to use `word-break: break-all;` as for Some of the languages the translated text is too long and it overflows out of the grid. The text 'Product Support' is dynamic.

**Update:**
I have a fixed width for the div with id, grid2. In one of the languages the translated text is too long, it's a Single word and it flows out of the grid2 div.

Updated the code too.

Comment: Can you add a simple live demo please? Because there is no need to set any word break rules for the current example above I think.

Comment: @Pangloss yeah for this particular grid I understand it's not needed but problem arises when I have a long word in one of the grids, where the text in the span overflows out of the div. Thanks for your suggestion. Will add a demo and notify you shortly.

Answer (score 27):

I have had good success in Chrome, Firefox and IE with using only:

```
word-break: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

In my problem case I was already using:

```
display: table-cell;
```

and I ended up having to include

```
max-width: 440px;
```

to get wrapping in all browsers.  In most cases the max-width was not necessary.

Comment: word-break: break-word; works only for blink/webkit so doesn't work in IE11 for me

Answer (score 1):

```
#grid2{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This should work for IE11, but not for IE9

Comment: It does not work for IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table-caption` to achieve what you are looking for.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k7ef2a4j/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="grid2">
     <span id="theSpan">Product Support</span>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#theSpan{
  display:table-caption;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey, forgot to mention one thing, I have a fixed width for the div with id, `grid2`. In one of the languages the translated text is too long, it's a Single word and it flows out of the grid2 div. I'll update the question as well. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As per your question, my above answer will resemble the `break-word` effect that you are looking for. Even if you have a fixed width, the characters would be broken like you have desired.

Comment: I understand, there is an issue if the text is a single word and is too long, for one of the languages it is. In that case the text in the span flows out of the div due to the fixed width of the div.

Comment: Yeah. I agree with you but if I put `word-break: break-word;` it works perfectly on Chrome. As in, if there are two words in the grid, it gets broken properly as shown in the 2nd image in the question. Also there is no problem with a longer text overflowing out of the div. Hence the title, "How to mimic word-break: break-word; for IE9, IE11 and Firefox" :) 
Hey, how about using a `div` instead of `span` to hold the text? Wonder if that would help. I shall try that.

Comment: If you have a word `asdfsdfsdfsadfsadf dsfsad`, so the second one will drop in both. But if you have the word `dsfsadfsdfsadfsdafsfsfsfsafsdfsafsadfsadfsdaf` it will render as one word only no matter what you try from above for any browser.

Comment: with Chrome it works fine if I have `word-break: break-word;` even for very long single word text. Amusing!

Comment: This worked for me. I dont know why it was voted down.