# How to separate words one by one with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make words one by one using CSS without `<br />` and without `width` define and without `ul li` basically I want to use with `h2` tag.

I want output like it:-

Patient
Chart
Calendar

See what I tried:-

```html
<h2 style="word-break: break-all; ">Patient Chart Calendar</h2>
```

Anybody can do it?
Thanks

Comment: Does it need to be done solely in CSS? It would be easy with JavaScript.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212909/can-css-force-a-line-break-after-each-word-in-an-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be a little bit hacky with the `word-spacing` property:

```html
<h2 style="word-spacing: 100vw;">Patient Chart Calendar</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
h2 {
  word-spacing: 999999px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Patient Chart Calendar</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but can you tell me what use of `999999px;` can i increase of decrease it?

Comment: It's a random number. Just make sure it is big enough. You just need to make sure the number is bigger than the widest screen you aim for.

Answer (score 1):

**Plz Try This**

```html
<h2 style="display: table-caption;">Patient Chart Calendar</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the /* Non standard for WebKit */
     word-break: break-word; modifier:

```
<p style="word-break: break-word">
<h2 style="word-break: break-word">
```

Chrome, Safari and other WebKit/Blink browsers support the unofficial break-word value.

See [How to mimic word-break: break-word; for IE9, IE11 and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532242/how-to-mimic-word-break-break-word-for-ie9-ie11-and-firefox) on support for IE

Answer (score -1):

You can use `<p>` paragraph tag like this-

```
<p>
<h2 >Patient</h2>
</p>
<p>
<h2 >Chart</h2>
</p>
<p>
<h2 >Calendar</h2>
</p>
```

no CSS needed..:)